# Email addresses giving internet connection

Tags: networking, email, internet

Mysterious email address giving internet connection.

I was looking on my computer settings and I found that it connects to an email address in order to get internet.

It has PPPoE

Username: something@[host].com

Password: ****

I followed the [host].com on my browser and it returned.

```
No forwarding set for [host].com
```

I am very suspicious how these email address work and I will be vary happy to learn how these work.

Comment: It's completely fine for a domain to be configured for email, but not run a web server. In this particular case, there is a web server, but it has not been configured for the domain, probably as a result of multiple domains sharing the same installation, but not all of them offering all services. That is totally normal, my own mail domain is set up like this.

Answer (score 20):

It's not actually an email address. It's a username styled like an email address. In fact, PPPoE doesn't do any authentication at all, but it's handled by an additional protocol like PPP or (MS-)CHAP. Either just uses the username as a plain string, and the protocol doesn't care if it looks like an email or just `username`, or even `www.host.com`. If it's a string, it's a valid username

Probably (although this is implementation dependent), the PPPoE/CHAP server uses a backend authentication service. This authentication server can have several "namespaces" for users (so they could have @host.com and @host2.com). Using an `@` as a separator is a convenient way to separate these, plus it gives the added benefit that users are already familiar with this format (from email addresses).

Note that `@host.com` doesn't even have to exist to have this scheme work, as it's never used to connect to a service.

Comment: Other systems also use user identifiers that look like email addresses, such as Active Directory’s `userPrincipalName` (UPN) and usernames in IRC.

Answer (score 13):

They're not email addresses – just usernames that happen to be in the form of "user@domain".

Many other systems besides email have a need to distinguish between user accounts that fall under different *administrative* domains, and many of them have adopted the "user@domain" syntax (in some such systems the @domain might not even have any relationship with DNS domains), but it could just as well have been "domain\user" or "domain::user" or "domain!user".

So in your case the "something@[host].com" only acts as your username for connecting to the ISP's PPPoE server (which is *kind of* like a VPN server except local), and the PPPoE server probably just uses the domain as part of the database lookup key (e.g. `WHERE name = 'something' AND domain = 'host.com'`) or even ignores it entirely.

All your IP packets are then tunneled through the PPPoE "VPN" connection instead of being sent directly.

As to why your ISP requires PPPoE *in the first place*, the exact reason is only known by the ISP – some ISPs use PPPoE for accounting reasons, sometimes it's a carryover from analog dial-up era (where PPP was always used), and sometimes it's used to distinguish multiple customers connected to a shared line (like students connected to a dorm ethernet).

Comment: Philosophical: If it uses the syntax of an E-Mail address, why isn't it an E-Mail address? Just because of context, or because of the fact that it is not assigned to a mailbox at the moment?

Comment: Same reason why words from different languages that happen to be spelled the same (or even homographs within the same language, for that matter) do not become the same word. The string "foo@bar" as a username in PPPoE _might_ have the same meaning as "foo@bar" in SMTP email (i.e. may refer to the exact same user), but in most cases they exist in different contexts that don't interact. (Though it depends on the system, as it's certainly possible to design a RADIUS server that use actual customer email addresses as PPPoE usernames, but that doesn't _make_ them email addresses, but the opposite.)

Comment: Also, in most cases the usernames _don't_ exactly use the syntax of an email address – they only have the same overall "a@b" format in common, but there may be syntactically valid usernames that are syntactically invalid email addresses and vice versa. RFC 7542 is a later attempt to define a unified syntax for "global" RADIUS usernames (i.e. recognized by systems worldwide) that actually takes the syntax rules from Internet email, but even then it diverges in some ways (see section 3.1).